# How to access nested JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to access "note_id" in a `JSON` object.

php code

```
<?php

$test = 
'{"username":"Ellaleeeeeee",
  "event_source":"browser",
  "event":
  "{
     \"notes\": [{\"note_id\": \"2771\"}]
  }"
}';

$jarray = json_decode($test, true);
$jevent = json_decode($jarray['event'], true);

var_dump($jevent);

?>
```

I tried `$jevent['notes']['note_id'][0]` but failed.

Please kindly tell me what I am supposed to do. Thanks!

Comment: `$jarray` is already decoded, no need to decode it again in `$jevent = ...`. `$jevent = $jarray['event'];`

Comment: @kerbholz Apparently the OP has another JSON string inside `event` which was initially a string.

Comment: @vivek_23 Yeah, realized this just now, thanks for pointing out

Comment: The order of your keys is incorrect. It should be `$jevent['notes'][0]['note_id']`.

Comment: it should be `$jevent['notes'][0]['note_id']` not `$jevent['notes']['note_id'][0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change code a bit like below:-

```
$jarray = json_decode($test, true);
$jevent = json_decode($jarray['event'], true);
echo $jevent['notes'][0]['note_id'];
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/0sOfm

In case you want to get all `note_id` then use `foreach()`

```
<?php

$test = 
'{"username":"Ellaleeeeeee",
  "event_source":"browser",
  "event":
  "{\"notes\": [{\"note_id\": \"2771\"},{\"note_id\": \"2772\"}]}"
}';

$jarray = json_decode($test, true);
$jevent = json_decode($jarray['event'], true);

foreach($jevent['notes'] as $jnotes){

    echo $jnotes['note_id'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/D7t0R

Comment: Thanks! I just edited the question because I wanna know whether indentation matters in this case. At the beginning, I formatted the code in that way and it didn't work out.